# Make columns the same width under merged cells (Header)

Tags: tables, columns

in the following table I merge the first two columns into one for it to be the header only on the first row, and underneath I have the state of my registers (0 and 1) for the rest of the rows still in two columns. How can I make it so from the second row until the end I get the two first columns to be equal in width?
How it is displayed now the first column is really thin and the second one occupies the rest of the header width.

The code I'm currently using:

```
\begin{table}[h]    
\centering
\caption{Registers GPIO\_PORT\_MODE\_L/H\_x control.}  
\label{tab:GPIOX_AF}    
\begin{tabular}{|cc|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{GPIO\_PORT\_MODE\_L/H\_x} & Function             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0}           & 0          & GPIOX function       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0}           & 1          & Alternate function A \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}           & 0          & Alternate function B \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}           & 1          & Alternate function C \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you replace the variable-width `c` column type with the fixed-width `w` column type for columns 1 and 2. Next, as is done in detail in the code given below, start calculating the *usable* width of columns 1 and 2 (called `\mylen`) by measuring the width of the string `GPIO\_PORT\_MODE\_L/H\_x`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newlength\mylen

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

% Calculate *usable* width of columns 1 and 2
\settowidth\mylen{GPIO\_PORT\_MODE\_L/H\_x}
\mylen=\dimexpr\mylen-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth\relax
\mylen=\dimexpr\mylen/2\relax

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\centering
\caption{Registers GPIO\_PORT\_MODE\_L/H\_x control.}
\label{tab:GPIOX_AF}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{ | wc{\mylen} | wc{\mylen} | l | }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{GPIO\_PORT\_MODE\_L/H\_x} & Function \\ \hline
0 & 0 & GPIOX function       \\ \hline
0 & 1 & Alternate function A \\ \hline
1 & 0 & Alternate function B \\ \hline
1 & 1 & Alternate function C \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked out perfectly!